# Value returned from useImperativeHandle() not always set to reference

Tags: reactjs

I have the following setup in order to share a reference between an instance of a `Filter` element and it's related context-provider.

I am not sure why, but for some reason the `filterRef` does not receive the value which I am returning in `useImperativeHandle()` inside the `Filter` component.

The problem comes to light as I am navigating back and forth between routes. For some reason, I need to "click twice" on the specific route in order to get a defined value for `filterRef.current`.

```js
export const ExploreFilterContext = createContext<FilterState | undefined>(undefined);

export const Explore = () => {
  const filterRef = useRef<FilterElement | undefined>(undefined);
  console.log('filterRef', filterRef);

  const params = useParams();
  const someDynamicComponent = getComponent(params);

  // ..
  useEffect(() => {
    setSubHeader({
      component: <Filter ref={filterRef} />,
    });
    const cleanUp = filterRef.current;
    return () => cleanUp?.resetFilters();
  }, [setSubHeader]);

  return (
    <ExploreFilterContext.Provider value={{ element: filterRef.current }}>
      {someDynamicComponent}
    </ExploreFilterContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```js
export const Filter = React.forwardRef<FilterElement | undefined, FilterProps>((props, ref) => {
  const refInstance: FilterElement = useFilterRef();
  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      console.log('imper', refInstance);
      return refInstance;
    },
    [refInstance],
  );
  // ...
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox? Looks like the ref is not given a value by the cycle you expect it to have it

Comment: @TusharShahi I'm logging it out to the console and it'll always return `current` as `null` whenever I am navigating from a sibling route to the one that is supposed to render the `Filter` component. Clicking the navigation-link a second time however, will set the value correctly. I'm currently not able to setup a sandbox example. Will do so as soon as I can. I would have expected everything to work as is. Coming from a different route means everything should be re-rendered and new states be created. No idea why this is not happening..